# Developing a Particular Hidden Markov Process

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

Consider a student who is working on
a coding project in which we observe how many times the student updates a given
file in a given week. A student is either "busy" or "not busy", and when a
student is busy, they update the file with a mean
rate of $2$ times a week, and when
a student is not busy, they update the file with a mean rate of $6$ times
a week. Given this structure, I would like to find the limiting observation
distribution of the number of times the student will update the file in the
week.

I can see that we have two hidden states, "busy" and "not busy" (hidden
states $1$ and $2$ respectively), and I see that I have two discrete
emission distributions based on these two hidden states (which I'm willing to
assume
are Poisson, but you can correct me if I am wrong). The question I am running
into is how to calculate the observation distribution at time $t$, given that
I have what seems to be two emisison distributions with non-finite support
(a student can update the file an arbitrary amount of times). How might this
affect the way we find the limiting observation distribution?
Note that for a standard first-order
Markov Chain with initial state distribution $\lambda$ and transition matrix
$P$, The limiting distribution was the $\lambda_t$ such that

$$\lambda_t = \lambda_{t-1} = \lambda P^{t-2}.$$

However, we are working with a hidden markov model,
and we are looking for the limiting distribution over a given week's observed
number of updates.

Comment: what is the *limiting observation distribution* ? is it merely the distribution of updates frequencies ?